# input focus from array

Tags: arrays, angular, input, focus

I have an Angular 2+ app which has a component with an array and I have an ngFor which I show and I bind with [(ngModel)] to the elements of the array.
I have a button which adds on click and empty record to the last element of the array to edit. What I want is to focus to the input field which is at the last element of the array.
I think I need to use ViewChildren for that (because it is an array) and not ViewChild. Most tutorials that I have found use ViewChild to focus to a single element. What I want is to focus to the input field of each new record.

Comment: May be this can help u 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62786384/set-focus-on-dynamically-created-input-on-angular/62788343#62788343

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would use ViewChildren for this. ViewChildren returns a QueryList, which has an accessor method for the first and last items in the QueryList intuitively called `last`. If your ViewChildren variable is called children, you can get the last element with `children.last`

Putting it all together,

`children.last.nativeElement.focus()`